# Image still has margins when trying to fill a div

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I would like an image to completely fill a div in my bootstrap grid layout. However, when I try the following it still leaves visible margins on the sides and at the bottom of the image. Here is my code:

```
<div class="container"
<div class="row equalheight">
        <div class="col-md-8 index-featured-image div-fill">
           <!--featured image -->
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 index-featured-about">
            <h2>this is about the featured post.</h2>
            <p>This is the content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.col-md-4 {
height: 100%;
background-color: green;
border-top:solid white 20px;
border-bottom:solid white 20px;
overflow: hidden;
}

.col-md-8 {
height: 100%;
background-color: black;
border-right: solid white 20px;
border-top:solid white 20px;
border-bottom:solid white 20px;
}

.col-md-8 img {
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
}
```

[Here's what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HFg2.png)

I appreciate any help! I've been trying to figure this out for hours!

Comment: First off close this div `<div class="container">`

Comment: Have you examined this in any browser's developer tools (Ctrl-Shift-I in Firefox or Chrome)?  This will tell you immediately what's wrong, and is ALWAYS the place to start for CSS layout problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `padding: 0;` to the div containing the `img` like this `.div-fill{padding: 0;}`

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/18/

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried this, but it only works partially---there's still slight padding at the bottom. Could another div or the container be interfering with the padding?

Comment: There can be a lot of different things causing that, if you provide more code I can take a look at it for you.

Comment: I figured it out! I tried it with a larger image and it worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your input!!